# Order: Create a new Status Category

Tags: order

I am creating a new Status type for the Order object. However it's asking me to select a "Status Category" and the options listed there are "Draft" and "Activated". Is there a way to create a new status category?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Status**

An indication of the stage that the order has reached in the order business process.

> You can add values to this picklist within two system-defined order
>   status categories: Draft and Activated. You can use these status
>   categories to track orders within your business process using reports
>   and views. Some user permissions apply specifically to draft statuses.
>   Others apply specifically to activated statuses.

**Properties of status:-**

> Create, Filter, Group, Restricted picklist, Sort, Update

hence you can create picklist value of this field

**StatusCode**

> The status category for the order. An order can be either Draft or
>   Activated. The label is Status Category.

**Properties of status code:-**

> Filter, Group, Restricted picklist, Sort, Update

There is no create option in properties So you cannot create the status category.

Hope it helps you.

References:-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_order.htm